# F# pattern matching to determine the state of a bank account based on past events

Tags: f#, state-machine

I am writing an event sourced system in which I need to have the state based on the events that already occurred for a given bank account.

The events are defined such as:

```
type AccountOpenedEvent = {
    AccountId: Guid
    Contact: Contact
    Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}

type AccountClosedEvent = {
    AccountId: Guid
    Reason: string
    Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}

type AccountCreditedEvent = {
    AccountId: Guid
    Amount: decimal
    Description: string
    Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}

type AccountDebitedEvent = {
    AccountId: Guid
    Amount: decimal
    Description: string
    Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}

type AddressChangeRequestedEvent = {
    AccountId: Guid
    NewAddress: Address
    Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}

type PhoneNumberChangeRequestedEvent = {
    AccountId: Guid
    NewPhoneNumber: PhoneNumber
    Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}

type EmailChangeRequestedEvent = {
    AccountId: Guid
    NewEmail: string
    Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}

type AddressChangeValidatedEvent = {
    AccountId: Guid
    NewAddress: Address
    Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}

type PhoneNumberChangeValidatedEvent = {
    AccountId: Guid
    NewPhoneNumber: PhoneNumber
    Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}

type EmailChangeValidatedEvent = {
    AccountId: Guid
    NewEmail: string
    Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}

type InvalidOperationAttemptedEvent = {
    Error: string
    Timestamp: DateTimeOffset
}

type Event =
    | AccountOpened of AccountOpenedEvent
    | AccountClosed of AccountClosedEvent
    | AccountCredited of AccountCreditedEvent
    | AccountDebited of AccountDebitedEvent
    | AddressChangeRequested of AddressChangeRequestedEvent
    | PhoneNumberChangeRequested of PhoneNumberChangeRequestedEvent
    | EmailChangeRequested of EmailChangeRequestedEvent
    | AddressChangeValidated of AddressChangeValidatedEvent
    | PhoneNumberChangeValidated of PhoneNumberChangeValidatedEvent
    | EmailChangeValidated of EmailChangeValidatedEvent
    | InvalidOperationAttempted of InvalidOperationAttemptedEvent
```

The projection system is defined as:

```
type Projection<'State,'Event> = {
    Init : 'State
    Update : 'State -> 'Event -> 'State
}

let project projection events =
    events |> Seq.fold projection.Update projection.Init
```

and the update function to update the state depending on the event received:

```
let updateAccountState (state : AccountState) (event : Event)=
    match event with
    | AccountOpened accountOpened ->
        match state.Status with
        | Some status ->
            match status with
            | AccountStatus.Opened when accountOpened.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot be opened cause it is already opened."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Opened when accountOpened.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot be opened cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Closed when accountOpened.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot be opened cause it is closed."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            // | AccountStatus.Closed when accountOpened.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
            | _ ->
                let message = "The account cannot be opened cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
        | None ->
            { state with
                Contact = Some accountOpened.Contact
                Status = Some AccountStatus.Opened
                Balance = Some 0m
                Created = Some accountOpened.Timestamp
                Updated = Some accountOpened.Timestamp
                Id = Some accountOpened.AccountId
            }
    | AccountClosed accountClosed ->
        match state.Status with
        | Some status ->
            match status with
            | AccountStatus.Opened when accountClosed.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                { state with
                    Status = Some AccountStatus.Closed
                    Updated = Some accountClosed.Timestamp
                }
            | AccountStatus.Opened when accountClosed.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot be closed cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Closed when accountClosed.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot be closed cause it is already closed."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            // | AccountStatus.Closed when accountClosed.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
            | _ ->
                let message = "The account cannot be closed cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
        | None ->
            let message = "The account cannot be closed cause it is not yet created."
            { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
    | AccountCredited accountCredited ->
        match state.Status with
        | Some status ->
            match status with 
            | AccountStatus.Opened when accountCredited.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                { state with
                    Balance = Some (state.Balance.Value + accountCredited.Amount)
                    Updated = Some accountCredited.Timestamp
                }
            | AccountStatus.Opened when accountCredited.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot be credited cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Closed when accountCredited.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot be credited cause it is closed."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            // | AccountStatus.Closed when accountCredited.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
            | _ ->
                let message = "The account cannot be credited cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
        | None ->
            let message = "The account cannot be credited cause it is not yet created."
            { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
    | AccountDebited accountDebited ->
        match state.Status with
        | Some status ->
            match status with 
            | AccountStatus.Opened when accountDebited.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                { state with
                    Balance = Some (state.Balance.Value - accountDebited.Amount)
                    Updated = Some accountDebited.Timestamp
                }
            | AccountStatus.Opened when accountDebited.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot be debited cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Closed when accountDebited.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot be debited cause it is closed."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            // | AccountStatus.Closed when accountDebited.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
            | _ ->
                let message = "The account cannot be debited cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
        | None ->
            let message = "The account cannot be debited cause it is not yet created."
            { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
    | AddressChangeRequested addressChangeRequested ->
        match state.Status with
        | Some status ->
            match status with 
            | AccountStatus.Opened when addressChangeRequested.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                { state with
                    NewAddressRequested = Some addressChangeRequested.NewAddress
                    Updated = Some addressChangeRequested.Timestamp
                }
            | AccountStatus.Opened when addressChangeRequested.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot receive an address change request cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Closed when addressChangeRequested.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot receive an address change request cause it is closed."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            // | AccountStatus.Closed when addressChangeRequested.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
            | _ ->
                let message = "The account cannot receive an address change request cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
        | None ->
            let message = "The account cannot receive an address change cause it is not yet created."
            { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
    | PhoneNumberChangeRequested phoneNumberChangeRequested ->
        match state.Status with
        | Some status ->
            match status with 
            | AccountStatus.Opened when phoneNumberChangeRequested.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                { state with
                    NewPhoneNumberRequested = Some phoneNumberChangeRequested.NewPhoneNumber
                    Updated = Some phoneNumberChangeRequested.Timestamp
                }
            | AccountStatus.Opened when phoneNumberChangeRequested.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot receive a phone number change request cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Closed when phoneNumberChangeRequested.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot receive a phone number change request cause it is closed."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            // | AccountStatus.Closed when addressChangeRequested.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
            | _ ->
                let message = "The account cannot receive a phone number change request cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
        | None ->
            let message = "The account cannot receive a phone number change cause it is not yet created."
            { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
    | EmailChangeRequested emailChangeRequested ->
        match state.Status with
        | Some status ->
            match status with 
            | AccountStatus.Opened when emailChangeRequested.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                { state with
                    NewEmailRequested = Some emailChangeRequested.NewEmail
                    Updated = Some emailChangeRequested.Timestamp
                }
            | AccountStatus.Opened when emailChangeRequested.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot receive an email change request cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Closed when emailChangeRequested.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot receive an email change request cause it is closed."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            // | AccountStatus.Closed when emailChangeRequested.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
            | _ ->
                let message = "The account cannot receive an email change request cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
        | None ->
            let message = "The account cannot receive an email change request cause it is not yet created."
            { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
    | AddressChangeValidated addressChangeValidated ->
        match state.Status with
        | Some status ->
            match status with 
            | AccountStatus.Opened
                when addressChangeValidated.AccountId = state.Id.Value
                     && addressChangeValidated.NewAddress = state.NewAddressRequested.Value ->
                let contact = { state.Contact.Value with Address = state.NewAddressRequested.Value }
                { state with
                    Contact = Some contact
                    Updated = Some addressChangeValidated.Timestamp
                    NewAddressRequested = None
                }
            | AccountStatus.Opened
                when addressChangeValidated.AccountId = state.Id.Value
                     && addressChangeValidated.NewAddress <> state.NewAddressRequested.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot validate an address change request cause the request was made for a different address."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Opened when addressChangeValidated.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot validate an address change request cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Closed when addressChangeValidated.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot validate an address change request cause it is closed."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            // | AccountStatus.Closed when addressChangeValidated.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
            | _ ->
                let message = "The account cannot validate an address change request cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
        | None ->
            let message = "The account cannot validate an address change cause it is not yet created."
            { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
    | PhoneNumberChangeValidated phoneNumberChangeValidated ->
        match state.Status with
        | Some status ->
            match status with 
            | AccountStatus.Opened
                when phoneNumberChangeValidated.AccountId = state.Id.Value
                     && phoneNumberChangeValidated.NewPhoneNumber = state.NewPhoneNumberRequested.Value ->
                let contact = { state.Contact.Value with PhoneNumber = state.NewPhoneNumberRequested.Value }
                { state with
                    Contact = Some contact
                    Updated = Some phoneNumberChangeValidated.Timestamp
                    NewPhoneNumberRequested = None
                }
            | AccountStatus.Opened
                when phoneNumberChangeValidated.AccountId = state.Id.Value
                     && phoneNumberChangeValidated.NewPhoneNumber <> state.NewPhoneNumberRequested.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot validate a phone number change request cause the request was made for a different phone number."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Opened when phoneNumberChangeValidated.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot validate a phone number change request cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Closed when phoneNumberChangeValidated.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot validate a phone number change request cause it is closed."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            // | AccountStatus.Closed when phoneNumberChangeValidated.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
            | _ ->
                let message = "The account cannot validate a phone number change request cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
        | None ->
            let message = "The account cannot validate a phone number change cause it is not yet created."
            { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
    | EmailChangeValidated emailChangeValidated ->
        match state.Status with
        | Some status ->
            match status with 
            | AccountStatus.Opened
                when emailChangeValidated.AccountId = state.Id.Value
                     && emailChangeValidated.NewEmail = state.NewEmailRequested.Value ->
                let contact = { state.Contact.Value with PhoneNumber = state.NewPhoneNumberRequested.Value }
                { state with
                    Contact = Some contact
                    Updated = Some emailChangeValidated.Timestamp
                    NewEmailRequested = None
                }
            | AccountStatus.Opened
                when emailChangeValidated.AccountId = state.Id.Value
                     && emailChangeValidated.NewEmail <> state.NewEmailRequested.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot validate an email change request cause the request was made for a different phone number."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Opened when emailChangeValidated.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot validate an email change request cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Closed when emailChangeValidated.AccountId = state.Id.Value ->
                let message = "The account cannot validate an email change request cause it is closed."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            // | AccountStatus.Closed when emailChangeValidated.AccountId <> state.Id.Value ->
            | _ ->
                let message = "The account cannot validate an email change request cause the account id does not match this account."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
        | None ->
            let message = "The account cannot validate a phone number change cause it is not yet created."
            { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
    | InvalidOperationAttempted invalidOperationAttempted ->
        { state with
            AuditInvalidations = invalidOperationAttempted.Error :: state.AuditInvalidations
            Updated = Some invalidOperationAttempted.Timestamp
        }
```

I found my implementations being a wee bit redundant about the points below:

- the `option` check (ie. `Some` / `None`) not sure how it can be avoided or refactored to make the pattern matching "lighter"
- the `Id` check for the same reasons

I am not too sure how can this be changed and have something more readable.

Comment: @dfhwze I think so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, I would change `AccountState` to the following:

```
type AccountStatus =
    | Uninitialized
    | Opened
    | Closed
```

In this way you have the full life cycle of an account and you then can avoid `Some/None` for the account status

---

The `AccountState` could then be changed to:

```
type AccountState = {
    Id: Guid
    Status: AccountStatus
    AuditInvalidations: string list
    Contact: Contact
    Balance: decimal
    Created: DateTimeOffset option
    Updated: DateTimeOffset option
    NewAddressRequested: Address option
    NewPhoneNumberRequested: PhoneNumber option
    NewEmailRequested: string option
   }
```

Where `option` is removed from fields that IMO shouldn't be optional: An Account without an `Id` or a `Contact` seems rather scary to me and the `Balance` has always a value (that may be `0.0m`), and with the `AccountStatus.Uninitialized`, `Status` can also always have a value.

---

In `updateAccountState` you can consider to evaluate the `Id` at the first match level in order to get rid of repetitive checks of it. Below is the first two matches as examples:

```
let updateAccountState (state : AccountState) (event : Event)=
    match event with
    | AccountOpened account ->
        match account.AccountId with
        | id when id = state.Id ->
            match state.Status with
            | AccountStatus.Opened ->
                let message = "The account cannot be opened cause it is already opened."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Closed ->
                let message = "The account cannot be opened cause it is closed."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Uninitialized ->
                { state with
                    Contact = account.Contact
                    Status = AccountStatus.Opened
                    Balance = 0m
                    Created = Some account.Timestamp
                    Updated = Some account.Timestamp
                    Id = account.AccountId
                }
        | _ -> 
            let message = "The account cannot be opened cause the account id does not match this account."
            { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
    | AccountClosed account ->
        match account.AccountId with
        | id when id = state.Id ->
            match state.Status with
            | AccountStatus.Opened ->
                { state with
                    Status = AccountStatus.Closed
                    Updated = Some account.Timestamp
                }
            | AccountStatus.Closed ->
                let message = "The account cannot be closed cause it is already closed."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
            | AccountStatus.Uninitialized ->
                let message = "The account cannot be closed cause it is not yet created."
                { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
        | _ ->
            let message = "The account cannot be closed cause the account id does not match this account."
            { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
```

This is IMO more clear and easy to follow.

---

**Update**

All your `AccountXXXEvent` events have `AccountId` and `Timestamp` in common, so these properties could be placed on `Event` and then `AccountXXXEvent` could be discriminated unions as well:

```
type AccountEvent =
    | AccountOpenedEvent of Contact: Contact
    | AccountClosedEvent of Reason: string
    | AccountCreditEvent of Amount:decimal * Description:string
    | etc...
```

`Event` could then look like:

```
type Event = Event of Id:Guid * Timestamp:DateTimeOffset * AccountEvent:AccountEvent
```

and finally `updateAccountState` as:

```
let updateAccountState (state : AccountState) (event : Event) =
    match event with
    | Event(id, timestamp, accountEvent) ->
        match id with
        | stateId when stateId = state.Id ->
            match accountEvent with
            | AccountOpenedEvent contact ->
                match state.Status with
                | AccountStatus.Opened -> invalidate state "The account cannot be opened cause it is already opened."
                | AccountStatus.Closed -> invalidate state "The account cannot be opened cause it is closed."
                | AccountStatus.Uninitialized ->
                    { state with
                        Contact = contact
                        Status = AccountStatus.Opened
                        Balance = 0m
                        Created = Some timestamp
                        Updated = Some timestamp
                        Id = id
                    }
            | AccountClosedEvent reason -> 
                match state.Status with
                | AccountStatus.Opened ->
                    { state with
                        Status = AccountStatus.Closed
                        Updated = Some timestamp
                    }
                | AccountStatus.Closed -> invalidate state "The account cannot be closed cause it is already closed."
                | AccountStatus.Uninitialized -> invalidate state "The account cannot be closed cause it is not yet created."
            | // TODO all the other events
        | _ -> 
            invalidate state "The transaction can not be fulfilled because the ids don't match."
```

where `invalidate` is defined as:

```
let invalidate state message = { state with AuditInvalidations = message :: state.AuditInvalidations }
```

Comment: thanks, interesting suggestions, I am gonna refactor my code